# Problema com Python ler alguns caracteres de um arquivo

Tags: python, json, caracteres

O código busca alguns textos de um arquivo *.json*, mas alguns caracteres acabam sendo trocados e saindo desta forma:

- sistemÃ¡tico
- balbÃºrdia

Estou imaginando que seja um problema com a codificação do arquivo ou com a forma de ler.

```
with open('text_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score -3):

O problema estava com a forma de ler o arquivo. É necessário especificar a codificação.

```py
with open('text_file.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

[Resposta base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599091/cant-read-a-special-character-%CC%81-in-python?newreg=82b563ae3b4a45ef90e09bb20ec36536)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).